# Command-line program to update R Markdown code to use `$latex` delimter

Tags: r, sed, awk, mathjax, rstudio

**UPDATE (13th June 2012):** [RStudio now supports a range of mathjax delimtiers](http://www.rstudio.org/docs/authoring/using_markdown_equations) including single dollar signs and double dollar signs without `latex`.

---

In 0.96 [RStudio changed its Mathjax syntax](http://blog.rstudio.org/2012/05/25/mathjax-syntax-change/) from `$<equation>$` to `$latex <equation>$` for inline equations and from `$$<equation>$$` to `$$latex <equation>$$` for displayed equations.

Thus, in summary:

> The revised syntax adds a `latex` qualifier to the $ or $$ equation begin delimiter.

I have some existing scripts that use the original `$` delimiter and I would like to update them to use the new `$latex` delimiter.
I was thinking that sed or awk might be suitable.

Also dollars that appear in r code blocks like this should not be altered.

````
```{r ...}
x <- Data$asdf
```
````

#### Question

- What would be a good simple command-line program perhaps using sed or awk to update my R Markdown code to use the newer mathjax delimiter in R Studio?

### Working example 1

Original text:

````
$y = a + b x$ is the formula.
This is some text, and here is a displayed formula
$$y = a+ bx\\
x = 23$$

```{r random_block}
y <- Data$asdf
```

and some more text     
$$y = a+ bx\\
x = 23$$
````

after transformation becomes

````
$latex y = a + b x$ is the formula.
This is some text, and here is a displayed formula
$$latex y = a+ bx\\
x = 23$$

```{r random_block}
y <- Data$asdf
```

and some more text     
$$latex y = a+ bx\\
x = 23$$
````

### Working example 2

```
`r opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)`
<!-- some comment -->

Some text

<!-- more -->
Observed data are $y_i$ where $i=1, \ldots, I$.  
$$y_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$$

Some text $\sigma^2$ blah blah $\tau$. 

$$\tau = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}$$

blah blah $\mu$ and $\tau$

$$\mu \sim N(0, 0.001)$$
$$\tau \sim \Gamma(0.001, 0.001)$$
```

should become

```
`r opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)`
<!-- some comment -->

Some text

<!-- more -->
Observed data are $latex y_i$ where $latex i=1, \ldots, I$.  
$$latex y_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$$

Some text $latex \sigma^2$ blah blah $latex \tau$. 

$$latex \tau = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}$$

blah blah $latex \mu$ and $latex \tau$

$$latex \mu \sim N(0, 0.001)$$
$$latex \tau \sim \Gamma(0.001, 0.001)$$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you:

````
sed '/^```{r/,/^```$/b;/^`r/b;:a;/\\\\$/{$!{N;ba}};s/\(\$\$\)\([^$]*\(\$[^$]*\)*\$\$\)\|\(\$\)\([^$]*\$\)/\1\4latex \2\5/g' file
````

N.B. The `r codeblock` code may need to be extended/altered as from the example code it is not obvious what it constitutes.

Answer (score 4):

Using `perl` and a look-back, should do the trick:

```
perl -pe 's/\b(?<=\$)(\w+)\b /latex $1 /g' file.txt
```

Make the changes in-line with the `-i` flag:

```
perl -pe -i 's/\b(?<=\$)(\w+)\b /latex $1 /g' file.txt
```

**EDIT:**

Try this monster:

```
perl -pe 's/\b(?<=\$)(\w+)\b(\$?)([ =])/latex $1$2$3/g;' -pe 's/(?<=\$)(\\\w+)/latex $1/g' file.txt
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for that; it appears to have worked on my first example, but not on my actual script; I've added a second example that hopefully captures more of the features of the text.

Comment: Thanks. "The monster" works pretty well. There are still a few little issues e.g., (a) dollar signs that occur within latex $$ areas; (b) I had an issue with `$j$th` appearing as `$j$latex th`. (c) `summary(jags.samples)$statistics` in an r code block became `summary(jags.samples)$latex statistics`  But these are pretty minor and easy to manually fix. And I guess that's the point of these scripts.;

Comment: I'm unsure whether to award this the answer or not. I really appreciate the script, and I imagine part of the problem is that I didn't provide enough examples; but the more I go through my actual old mathjax scripts, I'm actually getting quite a lot of false hits and misses. Thus, I'm not sure whether the script beats a more  manual approach. I've '+1'ed the answer instead.

Comment: Now perhaps you understand why we (RStudio) were fooled into making the `$latex` syntax change in the first place--it is VERY hard to come up with a set of rules that is reliable. That said, user feedback in the last week has convinced us that requiring `$latex` was a net negative, so we'll be changing it back. (`$latex ...$` will continue to work, but now so will `$...$`.) This latest change should be rolling out in the dailies at the end of this week or beginning of next week. Thanks for your patience, this is all pretty new territory for us.